# Problema en relación de tablas SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buenas tardes estoy realizando una base de datos y tengo un error al relacionar alguna de mis tablas.

Tabla Categorias:

```
create table Categorias
(
    CodCategoria_Cat varchar (5) NOT NULL,
    Descripcion_Cat varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Estado_Cat bit NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_CATEGORIAS PRIMARY KEY (CodCategoria_Cat)
)
go
```

Tabla Artículos:

```
create table Articulos
(
    CodArticulo_Ar varchar(5) NOT NULL,
    CodCategoria_Ar varchar(5) NOT NULL,
    Descripcion_Ar varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Estado_Ar bit NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_ARTICULOS PRIMARY KEY (CodArticulo_Ar, CodCategoria_Ar),
    CONSTRAINT FK_ARTICULOS_CATEGORIAS FOREIGN KEY (CodCategoria_Ar) 
    REFERENCES Categorias(CodCategoria_Cat)
)
go
```

Tabla Proveedores:

```
create table Proveedores
(
    CodProveedor_Pr varchar(5) NOT NULL,
    RazonSocial_Pr varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Contacto_Pr varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Telefono_Pr varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_PROVEEDORES PRIMARY KEY(CodProveedor_Pr),
)
Go
```

Tabla ArticulosXProveedores:

```
create table ArticulosxProveedores
(
    CodArticulo_AXP varchar(5) NOT NULL,
    CodProveedor_AXP varchar(5) NOT NULL,
    Stock_AXP int NOT NULL,
    PrecioUnitario_AXP decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_ARTICULOSXPROVEEDORES PRIMARY KEY (CodArticulo_AXP, CodProveedor_AXP),
    CONSTRAINT FK_ARTICULOSXPROVEEDORES_ARTICULOS FOREIGN KEY (CodArticulo_AXP) REFERENCES Articulos (CodArticulo_Ar),
    CONSTRAINT FK_ARTICULOSXPROVEEDORES_PROVEEDORES FOREIGN KEY (CodProveedor_AXP) REFERENCES Proveedores (CodProveedor_Pr)
)
Go
```

Cuando corro el script me salta el siguiente error:

```
There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'Articulos' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK_ARTICULOSXPROVEEDORES_ARTICULOS'.
```

No entiendo porque el error si yo tengo una foreign key en ArticulosXProveedores que es CodArt_AXP que hace referencia a CodArticulo_Ar de la tabla Artículos.

Comment: ¿Los códigos de los artículos se pueden repetir si están en distinta categoría?

Comment: No, no se tendrían que repetir, los códigos de articulo son únicos. @LuisCazares

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que la llave primaria de la tabla `Articulos` contiene también la columna `CodCategoria_Ar`. Al no necesitar el código de la categoría para hacer única la llave, puedes quitarlo de la llave.

De esa forma, la llave foránea de la tabla `ArticulosxProveedores` concordará con la llave primaria de `Articulos`.